# Java - Cannot find HttpClient.executeMethod()

Tags: java, file-upload, httpclient, java-io

I'm trying to upload a file with Apache's HTTP Client and MultipartRequests, but it gives me an error, here's my code:

```
PostMethod filePost = new PostMethod("http://host/some_path");
Part[] parts = {
  new StringPart("param_name", "value"),
  new FilePart(f.getName(), f)
 };
filePost.setRequestEntity(
  new CountingMultipartRequestEntity(parts, filePost.getParams())
  );
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
int status = client.executeMethod(filePost);
```

It says "Cannot find symbol executeMethod()".
It's strange because I based my code on examples I found on Internet, and when I copy/paste their code, it shows me errors!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using [HtppClient 4.x](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/) (see [`DefaultHttpClient`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html)) while the example code is based on [HttpClient 3.x](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) (see [`HttpClient`](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpClient.html)). The API has been changed completely between these versions.

Just include HttpClient 4 on your CLASSPATH and get rid of version 3.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you double-checked that you are using the same version these samples were written for? Maybe [this](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/index.html) will help.